# Xcode switch/case completion and warnings

Tags: objective-c, autocomplete, xcode4.5

How can I have XCode (4.5, 4G182) complete the case in a switch/case construction, and warn me about missing cases ?

For example:

```
for (int i=0;i<[flat elementCount];i++) {
    NSPoint elements[3];
    NSBezierPathElement elem=[flat elementAtIndex:i associatedPoints:elements];
    switch (elem ) {
        case NSMoveToBezierPathElement: break;
        case NSLineToBezierPathElement: break;
        case
```

I have seen this in the past. It also warned me about missing cases once the block was closed. How can you achieve this is XCode 4.5 ?

Edit: Check Switch Statements IS enabled, and I don't have a warning.

Here is a small example in which the completion works:

```
typedef enum  {
    kThisCase = 0,
    kThatValue = 1,
    kLastOne = 2
} myEnum;

myEnum var= kLastOne;

switch (var) {
    case kThatValue: break;
    case kLastOne: break;
    case
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> here gives me the remaining possible value of myEnum

[image: completion is working]
[image: completion is not working]

In the case of NSBezierPathElement completion, when I add this:

```
typedef enum {
    NSMoveToBezierPathElement,
    NSLineToBezierPathElement,
    NSCurveToBezierPathElement,
    NSClosePathBezierPathElement
} NSBezierPathElement;
```

(copied from the quick help panel) before the switch construction, the autocomplete works, but the warnings don't.

### Content of NSBezierPath.h

```
enum {
    NSMoveToBezierPathElement,
    NSLineToBezierPathElement,
    NSCurveToBezierPathElement,
    NSClosePathBezierPathElement
};
typedef NSUInteger NSBezierPathElement;
```

Is it the explanation for the completion not working? Isn't this enum supposed to be the type of NSBezierPathElement ?

This doesn't match the quick help panel. In the quick help panel, I have this: `typedef enum {   NSMoveToBezierPathElement,   NSLineToBezierPathElement,
   NSCurveToBezierPathElement,   NSClosePathBezierPathElement} NSBezierPathElement;`

Answer (score 3):

You need a compiler setting which is enabled by default. Search for 'case' in build settings, and the one (title) named 'Check Switch Statements', this is GCC_WARN_CHECK_SWITCH_STATEMENTS.

I think this needs that the enum has actually been defined correctly, not as an NSInteger and the like. If constants are integers, not an enum, then the check will not help because compiler has no knowledge integers are related.

Also, very important, remove the default: clause. If it's there, then you are handling implicitly all missing cases in this one, so no warning is triggered!

Comment: +1 however, clang *will* warn you if you implement a `default` when/if all cases are handled and you have also enabled `-Wcovered-switch-default`.